# how to config .htaccess to prevent www.parent.com/child access www.child.com

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I have a unix shared hosting where I have:

```
/  
.htaccess
a.html
....
child/
   .htaccess
   b.html
   ......
```

The www.parent.com points to /
The www.child.com points to /child

I have to prevent the access to www.parent.com/child  without stopping www.child.com from working.
The result can be a redirect, a 404 or access denied.
The .htaccess files are based on the html5boilerplate .htaccess file.

I tried modified the /.htaccess without success:

Attempt #1:

```
<Directory /child>
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
 </Directory>
```

--> The child.com stopped working.

Attempt #2:

```
 RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^.*parent.com.*$ [NC]
 RewriteRule ^.*/child.*$ / [NC]
```

--> Nothing happens. I also tried different regex combinations.

Attempt #3:

```
  <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}   ^.*child.*$              [NC]
     RewriteRule ^    /   [R=302.L]     
   </IfModule>
```

--> Nothing happens. I known this one is brute force, but it was after trying main less aggressive options.

I known that RewriteEngine is on, because this works:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
     RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\..+$ [NC]
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=localhost [NC]
     RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !=127.0.0.1
     RewriteRule ^ http://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: When dealing with `RewriteRule`, path is passed without leading slash, please try `Attempt #2` with modifying second line to `RewriteRule ^child.*$ - [R=404]` (This should return 404 error)

Comment: I tried something similar before, and now i tried exactly the way you wrote, still without any success.

I tried to clear the caching, and change browser to make sure I'm with a clean cache.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this rule as very first rule inside `/child/.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?child\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ - [F,L]
```

Comment: perfect! I tried so many combinations and nothing worked.  

I was hoping mostly to work directly on the parent.com since I have several child.com but it works well! It's all I need.